# Find all shares on a domain

Tags: powershell, network-share

Is it possible to find all the network shares on a domain using powershell?

I've tried the following:

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Share -ComputerName test1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to run a script that will list all shares. It must be run on Windows Server or a computer that has Microsoft RSAT installed.

1. Install RSAT (if required).
2. On each target computer, run `winrm quickconfig` to allow remote WMI calls.
3. Run the following powershell script.

FindAllShares.ps1

```
#This must be run on a computer that has the ActiveDirectory module installed (eg. Windows Server)
#The module can be installed using the RSAT suite from Microsoft. 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#To connect to remote computers, the following needs to be run on them:
#winrm quickconfig

#Get all the computers on the domain
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {enabled -eq $true} | select DNSHostName, Name

$skipComputers = @("COMPUTER1", "COMPUTER2") #This is a list of computers to not check
$skipShares = @("ADMIN$", "IPC$")
$allShares = @()

#Loop through all of the computers and ask each for their shares
foreach ($computer in $computers | sort Name)
{
    #Write-Host $computer.DNSHostName

    if ($skipComputers -contains $computer.Name)
    {
        #skip these computers
    } else
    {
        #Write-Host $computer.Name

        #Get the shares on this computer
        $shares = Invoke-Command -Computer $computer.DNSHostName -ScriptBlock {Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Share}

        foreach ($share in $shares)
        {
            #Write-Host $share.Name

            if ($skipShares -contains $share.Name)
            {
                #skip these shares
            } else
            {
                $sharePath = "\\$($computer.Name)\$($share.Name)"
                #Write-Host $sharePath

                $allShares += $sharePath
            }
        }
    }
}

#Write-host $($allShares -join ";")
Write-host $($allShares | Out-String)
```

Comment: I honestly appreciate you sharing your discovery. I would also like to point out that this script assumes that winrm is configured on every machine. And sometimes, configuring it may not be an option. `Invoke-command` is what requires WinRM to be configured. `Get-WmiObject` does not. Since you are already using `Get-WmiObject` we could use the `-ComputerName` parameter on it to completely eliminate the use of `Invoke-Command`. Would that still work?

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Rohin. Using Get-WmiObject makes a lot of sense. I believe it too needs a service running and a firewall setting in order to work. I'll post if I get that to work :)

Comment: It utilizes the RPC protocol which is an essential service and is always on. And firewall might require TCP Port 135. In an standard corporate network, it would be open for all internal subnets. DMZs maybe a different story.